# In Windows batch programming how do I pass %* into a command

Tags: windows, batch-file

How do I take the parameters stored in %* for a batch program and pass them to another command.  Below is a simplified version of what I am trying to do.

I have a batch file called robocopy-test.bat with the following inside

```
robocopy %1 %2 %*
```

I call it like this:

```
.\robocopy-test.bat C:\Temp\from C:\Temp\to test1.txt test2.txt test3.txt
```

And I get:

```
    C:\tools>robocopy C:\Temp\from C:\Temp\to C:\Temp\from C:\Temp\to test1.txt test2.txt test3.txt

-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
   ROBOCOPY     ::     Robust File Copy for Windows
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

  Started : Tue Jun 12 16:21:18 2018

   Source - C:\Temp\from\
     Dest - C:\Temp\to\

    Files :
  Options : /COPY:DAT /R:1000000 /W:30

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

ERROR : Invalid Parameter #3 : "C:\Temp\from"

       Simple Usage :: ROBOCOPY source destination /MIR

             source :: Source Directory (drive:\path or \\server\share\path).
        destination :: Destination Dir  (drive:\path or \\server\share\path).
               /MIR :: Mirror a complete directory tree.

    For more usage information run ROBOCOPY /?


****  /MIR can DELETE files as well as copy them !
PS C:\tools> .\robocopy-test.bat C:\Temp\from C:\Temp\to test1.txt test2.txt test3.txt
```

Comment: Why aren't you just executing it as `robocopy %*`.  You are putting in the parameters correctly from the command line so I am not sure why you want to use %1 and %2.

Comment: Just to expand upon the above, `%*` is all arguments, which means it already includes `%1` and `%2`.

Comment: Good point.  Again, my real scenario is more complicated, but I think just using %* and nothing else may still work if I move things around a bit.  I'll try that.

Comment: That worked.  I misunderstood what %* meant.  Someone should turn the comments into an answer.

Comment: If you looked at the first line of your output you posted it should seem pretty obvious to you now.  We will chalk this one up to a typo.  You can probably just delete this question.

Comment: I didn't know how to use '%*'.  Something I looked at suggested it referred to the remainder of the parameters that haven't been looked at.  Of course when I found it, I was looking for something like Var Args in Java, so I came with a preconceived notion what it could mean which didn't serve me well.  Thanks for clarifying